# 「日本人論」というタグの必要性

Tags: discussion

[このような質問](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/42354/no-word-for-time-until-1871)がときどき投稿されますが、そこで質問の焦点に問題が生じると私は見ます。

質問をタイトルどおり解釈して回答すれば、「語源」の話になり、問題はないと思います。（幸い、その質問はそう対応されたようです）

が、質問の内容に、"For a long time the Japanese didn't have any interest in clocks"という引用が含まれており、質問を少しだけ幅広くすれば、古代日本の文化の成り立ちに触れることになります。しかも、引用文が「日本人」と一般的に述べています。

いかなる場においても、民族を無理やりひっくるめて語る文には危険性があると私は個人的に思いますが、この場合、このサイト上で、「日本人論」になりがちな質問に具体的にいかに応じるかを、少し議論していただきたいと思います。

そこで、選択肢が少なくとも二つあります：

１）「日本人論」や、それに触れる質問を"off-topic"にして、サイトの"Help"にその旨をはっきり書く。

２）「日本人論」のタグを作成し、そのような質問を歓迎する。

一応、放っておくことは選択の延期に過ぎないので、できれば避けたいと思います。

いかがですか。

Comment: "Japanese Culture" の Area 51 は消えたんでしたっけ…。

Comment: @brokenheadphones http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/59039/japanese-culture Unsuccessful proposals are eventually deleted...

Comment: 文化そのものより、日本（人）を珍しいもの扱いする問答が気がかりです。国内では、それが「日本人論」で、国外では「[オリエンタリズム](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%82%AA%E3%83%AA%E3%82%A8%E3%83%B3%E3%82%BF%E3%83%AA%E3%82%BA%E3%83%A0)」の形で現れるのではないかと。

Answer (score 8):

日本人論に限ったことではなく、境界領域の質問は多数投稿されてきます。「特定の格闘技の技の日本語解釈についての質問」とか「明朝体とゴシック体と毛筆体の使い分けについての質問」とか「直訳しても伝わらず、日本の法制度や商慣行にまで言及しないと説明困難な質問」とか。

複数の領域にまたがるような質問であっても、個人的には一定以上に「日本語」が絡んでいれば、大目に見るべきだと思います。「日本語のわび・さびの概念について説明してください」とか「ハレ・ケという言葉のニュアンスが分かりません」のような質問は許容されると思います。

かといって日本人論を積極的に歓迎するわけではありません。「葬式はハレに含まれますかケに含まれますか」といった類の質問はcloseされるべきでしょう。こういうのはもうルールを細かく作れば対応できるというものではないので、voting systemによって個別に判断するしかないのではないでしょうか。

私の意見としては「日本人論／日本文化論だけ敢えて名指ししてoff-topicとする必要はない」「日本人論というタグまでは作らない」です。つまり現状維持が最善だと感じます。

いずれにせよ、回答者は可能な限り「日本語」に絡むように回答すべきであり、文化論などに終始しないよう気をつけるべきだとは思います。

Answer (score 1):

元の記事は翻訳の段階で、明治政府が西暦を導入した年が1872年だったことを
解釈の変遷か何かで「時間の概念がない」というような響きになったと思われる
元がドイツ語で、英語を経由しているのでこの手の間違いはヨーロッパ圏では非常に多く残っています

日本語と日本の文化は切っても切れない関係ですが、
「日本人論」なるものは邪道だと思います